# Can I hide "sold" or "expired" items on the auction house search?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I'm shopping around at the auction house for a new piece of gear for my hero, I've often got a wide selection available.

Recently though, I've noticed that a good percentage of the items returned by the search have been sold.  Other times it shows me items that have expired.  That's no fun!  I don't want to look at things I *can't have* and should be jealous of - I want to see only stuff I can buy!

I imagine this is useful for market research, for pricing a new item for sale.  However, it's terribly useless when I'm trying to buy.

Is there any way to hide these unavailable items from my search results?

Comment: Just a possible thought, these items could be becomming unavailable post search. If they had realtime updates on the list it could get very confusing with things just disappearing.

Comment: @Emerica., I sometimes see them even right after I search, on the first page, and repeating the search doesn't remove them :(

Comment: Damn Blizzard and their auction house operating at 10% efficiency. It is down like half the time I want to get on anyway...

Comment: It's even more ghetto that they show up in Recommended Items...

Comment: With a database the size of the Auction House they are trying to maintain, I do not find it surprising that things don't update in real time. That is just too much to ask of the DB servers, at least right now while the game is at peak traffic.

Comment: @Tater596, at least give me a checkbox or something to toss those results on the client side....  Although now we're discussing in comments, which we should cut out :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently there is no way to hide the sold/expired listings.

Sometimes I actually find them helpful because I know for sure that something similar at the price they were listed at will sell.  I do this by altering my max buyout price until I have a rough idea of what the buyout of the sold item was.